# Spyder stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, spyder

I have recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and the first signs of regret are already showing up.

The upgrade went fine, but I've found out that Spyder, my all-time favourite Python IDE, has stopped working. Spyder is absolutely the best Python IDE I've ever come across, though it's a b*tch to install.

I thought I might get Spyder working again if I had it reinstalled with Synaptic. After all, it's the official Ubuntu way of installing and reinstalling stuff from the repos, right? With any/all dependencies resolved, etc.

But nothing happened after I reinstalled it with Synaptic and clicked the Spyder icon in the "Development" program group. Then I located the executable in the `/usr/bin/spyder` and executed it from a terminal, and the following error messages popped up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('spyder==4.2.1', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 209, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 45, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 44, in check_qt
    if LooseVersion(actual_ver) < LooseVersion(required_ver):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/version.py", line 52, in __lt__
    c = self._cmp(other)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/version.py", line 339, in _cmp
    if self.version == other.version:
AttributeError: 'LooseVersion' object has no attribute 'version'
```

I'm totally lost and I would hate to see Spyder go (although I'm tired of its installation tantrums). I tried Atom and PyCharm but they are total pieces of dung (IMHO) when compared to Spyder. Installing Spyder under Anaconda (the developer's suggestion) is not an option, as I don't want any more clutter on my machine to just run *one single* program. Besides, Synaptic should *always* work, right?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to install Spyder 4.2.1, which is an outdated version of Spyder. Because distributions like Ubuntu often contain outdated Spyder packages, Spyder ["strongly recommend[s]"](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#linux) not to install via a distribution package manager like `apt`, and instead to install using [Anaconda](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#anaconda) or [pip](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#using-pip).

Note: the most recent Spyder release (as of 2022/08/22) is [Spyder 5.3.2](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases).

However, if you still want to install version 4.2.1 of Spyder for some reason, it seems you should downgrade to Python 3.9, as `distutils` (the module where the error arose) is [deprecated in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html). Examining [the Spyder 4.2.1 `setup.py`](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/9c84cd89625d9ad07f54810588ae6464fa4efef1/setup.py) would indicate it supports some version of Python 3.9.

Comment: if I try to install 5.3.2 via pip I get a different error. I'm away from my computer right now, but I will post a note about it tonight.